# WPF C# image won't show even though I know the path is good

Tags: c#, wpf, image, file

I have to add an image from specific path to ImageSource field in class Ucenik.
Here are all the codes (possibly) connected to the problem:

This is the function that reads all data for the Observable collection
(class Skola has a field type Observablecollection).
The "else" part is important.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Skola> citaj(string putanja)
{
    ObservableCollection<Skola> skole = new ObservableCollection<Skola>();
    ObservableCollection<Ucenik> ucenicis = new ObservableCollection<Ucenik>();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(putanja))
    {
        string linija;
        while ((linija = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] delovi = linija.Split(";");
            if (delovi.Length == 4)
            {
                if (delovi[0] == "0")
                {
                    string naziv_s = delovi[1];
                    int id_s = int.Parse(delovi[2]);
                    string adresa_s = delovi[3];
                    Skola s = new Skola(id_s, naziv_s, adresa_s);
                    foreach(Ucenik u in ucenicis)
                    {
                        s.dodajUcenikaTest(u);
                    }
                    ucenicis.Clear();
                    skole.Add(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    string ime = delovi[0];
                    string prezime = delovi[1];
                    string adresa = delovi[2];
                    string jbmg = delovi[3];

                    string newFileName = "";
                    newFileName += ime;
                    newFileName += "_";
                    newFileName += prezime;
                    newFileName += ".png";
                    string newFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath_ucenik, newFileName);
                    if (File.Exists(newFilePath))
                    {
                        BitmapImage slika = new BitmapImage(new Uri(newFilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                        Ucenik u = new Ucenik(jbmg, ime, prezime, adresa, slika);
                        ucenicis.Add(u);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Ucenik u = new Ucenik(jbmg, ime, prezime, adresa);
                        ucenicis.Add(u);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I used the "citaj" function from class "Citac":

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Skola> skole=new ObservableCollection<Skola>();
private Skola NEUPISANI;
private Skola selected_skolice = new Skola();
private Citac citac = new Citac();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
/* --> */          skole = citac.citaj("Ucenici.txt");
    NEUPISANI=skole.ElementAt(0);
}
```

Here are some class "Ucenik":

```cs
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private string JMBG;
private string ime;
private string prezime;
private string adresa;
private ImageSource slika;

public Ucenik(string JMBG, string ime, string prezime, string adresa)
{
    this.ime = ime;
    this.prezime = prezime;
    this.adresa = adresa;
    this.JMBG = JMBG;
}

public Ucenik(string JMBG, string ime, string prezime, string adresa, ImageSource slika)
{
    this.ime = ime;
    this.prezime = prezime;
    this.adresa = adresa;
    this.JMBG = JMBG;
    this.slika = slika;
}
```

I have tested with message boxes if the code is recognizing the path to the photo and it does so I'm thinking the problem is maybe with constructor or something like that. Also, I should mention WPF when I add a photo it will show itm, it's just when it has to load itself up when starting the program, then it's not showing.

----EDIT----

I have fixed it by changing how I add the photo from this:

```
BitmapImage slika = new BitmapImage(new Uri(newFilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

to this:

```
BitmapImage slika = new BitmapImage();
slika.BeginInit();
slika.UriSource = new Uri(newFilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
slika.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
slika.EndInit();
```